# Add multiple elements to an array from a function called within the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This is probably a very simple question and has probably been answered before but I've researched it and I can't find anything. If I run the following code:

```
function addElements(arg1,arg2){
   return ['b','c'];
}

var arr = ['a',addElements('foo','bar'),'d'];
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Then I get an array like this:

```
  ['a',['b','c'],'d']
```

how can I make it create a single dimensional array like this

```
  ['a','b','c','d']
```

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're executing an anonymous function in the middle of an array definition...

Comment: var arr = ['a','b','c','d']; ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly?

Comment: The array definition builds up a collection of complex objects which a third party component uses to display a dialog. The function will be a utility method that is used in lots of places, I made it an anonymous function for brevity, ill edit the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on keeping this format, you can use `concat`:

```
var arr = ['a'].concat(function(){
    return ['b','c'];
}(), 'd');
alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

A cleaner approach and explanation:

```
// initial array
var arr = ['a'];

// use your function to add data to array
arr = arr.concat(function(){
  return ['b','c'];
}());

// add more values
arr.push('d');
```

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll I am assuming that OP doesn't want to create an array with 4 constants in it. They probably want to generate values to insert into the array dynamically, and just created an example with constants...

Comment: I can't (easily) do it the second way because this is within a very large block of json. The first way will work well though, thanks.

Comment: Why not `[].concat('a',function(){return ['b','c'];}(),'d');` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

> The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator and each value of the array (from left-to-right) to reduce it to a single value.

in combination with [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

> The `concat()` method returns a new array comprised of the array on which it is called joined with the array(s) and/or value(s) provided as arguments.

```js
var arr = ['a', function () { return ['b', 'c']; }(), 'd'],
    arr2 = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r.concat(a);
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```js
var arr = ['a', function () { return ['b', 'c']; }(), 'd'],
    arr2 = [];

arr.map(function (a) {
    arr2 = arr2.concat(a);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Interesting approach (I'd forgotten about reduce) but I'd imagine a single straight concat would be faster/less code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking a general solution for a data structure that can contains array inside array, and you want to flatten it.

You basically need a recursive method to do so if that the case, i.e.:

```
function flattenArr(arr) {
    var outArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            outArr = outArr.concat(flattenArr(arr[i]));
         } else {
            outArr.push(arr[i]);
         }
    }
    return outArr;
}
```